# How can I achieve Protractor support for Firefox 48 and up?

Tags: firefox, protractor, webdriver-manager

For quite sometime now I have been trying to run protractor with Firefox (Windows) v48 and above to run my AngularJS application. 
However, as per [protractor docs](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/browser-support.md):

> WebDriver support for Firefox has changed recently, and Firefox version
>   48 does not work properly with the current tools. For the moment, we
>   recommend testing against Firefox 47

This information was updated 3 years ago and nothing seems to have been done afterward.

**Versions**

- OS - Windows 10 64-bit
- Protractor - 5.4.2
- Firefox - 68
- selenium-stanalone-server: 2.53.1
- AngularJS - 1.6.9

I did raise an issue recently on [GitHub](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/5299) for the same, but it has not received traction yet.

I would like to know if anyone has been able to get around the issue for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Yikes, Firefox 48 is probably 2-ish years old. What you'll need to use is [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases). webdriver-manager should download the latest geckodriver automatically and you can either use direct connect or selenium standalone server to run this.

To download only the geckodriver binary, you could use:

```
webdriver-manager update --chrome false --standalone false
```

Note: chromedriver and selenium standalone jar file are downloaded automatically and these flags will turn them off.

When you want to start the server, you'll just use:

```
webdriver-manager start
```

or you could use `directConnect`. Direct connect will work as long as you used 
a local version of webdriver-manager. It will not work if you used a global installed version of webdriver-manager.

Comment: I am running E2E tests on Windows via Webstorm. So, I'm using selenium-stanalone-server: 2.53.1 which I build separately to create the jar. So, I'm not sure if I can use `webdriver-manager start`.

Comment: If you don't need to build it, you could download selenium standalone server similar to how we download chromedriver. If you use webdriver-manager, you can also download the selenium standalone server.

Comment: Could you re-open the github issue to update documentation with the latest supported Firefox version?